# Django ModelForm override widget

Tags: django, django-models

Disclaimer: I am a beginner with python and Django but have Drupal programming experience.

How can I override the default widget of this:

```
#models.py
class Project(models.Model):
color_mode = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, help_text='colors - e.g black and white, grayscale')
```

in my form with a select box? Is the following OK or am I missing something?

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('title', 'date_created', 'path', 'color_mode')
        colors = (
                   ('mixed', 'Mixed (i.e. some color or grayscale, some black and white)'),
                   ('color_grayscale', 'Color / Grayscale'),
                   ('black_and_white', 'Black and White only'),
                   )
        widgets = {'color_mode': Select(choices=colors)}
```

After reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets, I am lost since the example only discusses TextArea and the widgets discussion seems to exclude ModelForm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you want to override the widget for a formfield in general, the best way is to set the `widgets` attribute of the `ModelForm Meta` class:

To specify a custom widget for a field, use the `widgets` attribute of the inner `Meta` class. This should be a dictionary mapping field names to widget classes or instances.

For example, if you want the `CharField` for the `name` attribute of `Author` to be represented by a `<textarea>` instead of its default `<input type="text">`, you can override the field’s widget:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

The `widgets` dictionary accepts either widget instances (e.g., `Textarea(...)`) or classes (e.g., `Textarea`).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: This really deserves an upvote. But sadly, the django documents didn't mention how to add widgets to a model.form class. So stupid and disappointing. The django docs are tedious and long but didn't contain what are really important to developers.