# I need display ModelChoiceField like CharField

Tags: python, django

I have some form modelformset_factory with model contains ForeignKey, but I need display this ForeignKey(ModelChoiceField) like CharField.

I use like that:

```
class SingleNeedFormWithDescription(ModelForm):
    helper = StandardFormHelper()
    helper.template = 'template.html'
    need = CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = NeedMembershipOrganization
        fields = ['need', 'description']
```

I have id of need in my template, but I need `need.title` or `need.__str__()`.

My model:

```
class NeedMembershipOrganization(Model):
    need = ForeignKey('needs.Need')
    organization = ForeignKey(Organization)
    description = TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='description')
```

Thanks!

Comment: But how are you going to use it then? Foreign key would be rendered as a list of objects as dropdown, but if you override it with charfield, what do you  put in the text box?

Comment: You can get text input formfield with autocompletion by using `autocomplete-light`. Very useful when the related model has a large number of entries to choose from. 
https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22250192/1418794) on how to override default model form fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) widget to a [`TextInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput), but you might have to figure out some way to validate and parse the input.

```
class SingleNeedFormWithDescription(ModelForm):

    need = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Need.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.TextInput)
```