# Django admin, filter by timestamp range

Tags: python, django

I have a model with these attributes:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    timestamp = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timestamp = get_timestamp_in_milli()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my `admin.py` I have declared AdminModel with this model:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Is there any calendar like filter, where I can filter range of my timestamp? If yes how to include it?

I know that there is also filter based on `DateField`, is it possible to make timestamp filterable as `DateFiled`?

Comment: Why use `BigIntegerField` for timestamp when you have [`TimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#timefield)?

Comment: The default widget for `TimeField` is a [`TimeInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TimeInput), maybe that's what you are looking for?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil lets just say that I can't decide what kind of fields I can use :)

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you should still be able to use `TimeInput` as the widget.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil can you provide example? I'm just new to django.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22250192/2689986 and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get that range of dates (sidenote: `__range=[timestamp__lte, timestamp__gte]`) the normal way (i.e., `<input type="date" name="timestamp__lte"> <input type="date" name="timestamp__gte">`) from the client and then convert it in the server. [Here's a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python/8778548#8778548).

Comment: Where I do need to write this part of code? I'm just new to django.

Comment: [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range) is part of the QuerySet API. Is just a filter, as if you do `name__icontains="something"`. They are "magical" filters that can be used in the fields (depending of their type). The `<input>`s would need to be submitted via form, and then you would do something like `MyModel.objects.get(timestamp__range=[timestamp__lte, timestamp__gte])`, where the list are vars from POST (or GET).