# Save the dynamically populated value on dropdown

Tags: django, model, wagtail

I'm using wagtail CMS for Django, I want to add a dynamically populated value for a dropdown and save it on the Page model, this is my code:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    domain = CharField(max_length=10, choices=MY_CHOICES)
    subdomain = CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('', '------')]
```

I've got some frontend logic to populate dynamically the options for subdomain, but after I hit save I got: `The page could not be created due to validation errors` And in the subdomain field: `Select a valid choice. [my value] is not one of the available choices.`

I can't use ForeignKey to populate subdomain because it depends from an external API service that we're using.

I tried to use a custom field that inherits from `CharField` with no success, it looks it executes `validate` method only for the `domain` field.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `choices` argument, you have to predefine the list of possible values. Read the relevant part of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices) (last two paragraphs of that section).

You could omit the `choices` argument from the model field definition and only render a HTML `select` tag in the frontend (which is then filled with options dynamically, like you explained).

You could also look into changing the default widget of the `CharField` to a `select` tag, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22250192/9225671) and [this part of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) show.