# How to give user option to select a wagtail collection of images in page?

Tags: wagtail

I am looking for a way to show a list of wagtail collection as a field in a page (just like it showing when you upload an image). A user can select a collection and I can programmatically filter the images to the selected collection. I am still new to wagtail and I am not sure how should I implement this in code.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wagtail/FqNUT97-iyQ/zDSjbkdQBAAJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's a couple ways you can do this. The first, and probably the least-ideal way is to register Collection as a snippet and use a `SnippetChooserPanel`.

```
"""Register Collection snippet."""
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.core.models import Collection

# Register Collections as Snippets so we can use the SnippetChooserPanel to select a collection
register_snippet(Collection)
```

And then in your model you can use a SnippetChooserPanel, like so (note, this is all untested code)

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class CustomPage(Page):

    # ...
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Collection',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        # ...
        SnippetChooserPanel('collection'),
    ]
```

[@gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853523/gasman)'s comment on the answer [has a link to another solution that's much more elegant than mine.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wagtail/FqNUT97-iyQ/zDSjbkdQBAAJ)

Comment: Thanks, [@kalob-taulien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074077/kalob-taulien). I implemented the code in my dev environment and it working for me.

Comment: I try [@gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853523/gasman) approach but it didn't work. After I read [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457745/8059792) answer I understand, Django doesn't allow choices to be loaded as dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do this using [wagtail-generic-chooser](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-generic-chooser) just following the instructions on the `README.md`, and using wagtail core Collection model instead of People.

Answer (score 0):

Aug 2022 - Wagtail 2.15.5 - display Wagtail hierarchical collection

[image]

```
from wagtail.admin.templatetags.wagtailadmin_tags import format_collection

class Meeting(models.Model):

    COLLECTION_CHOICES = []
    for c in Collection.objects.all():
        COLLECTION_CHOICES.append((c.id, format_collection(c)))

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text="Choose the 'Collection' folder for the meeting's related documents", choices=COLLECTION_CHOICES)
```

Edit: If you add a new collection to collections and go back the this Meeting model the new collection will not be in the list. As the COLLECTION_CHOICES is only created once for optimization. If you want a dynamic collection choice you need to make a custom form on top of your model e.g.

```
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminModelForm

class MeetingAdminForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    # This below field will be automatically added to the Meeting panel fields
    meeting_collection = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MeetingAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['meeting_collection'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            initial=self.instance.collection_id,
            choices=[(c.id, format_collection(c)) for c in Collection.objects.all()]
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        instance.collection_id = self.cleaned_data['meeting_collection']
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

class Meeting(models.Model):

    base_form_class = MeetingAdminForm

    class Meta:
        """ Meta options """
        ordering = ['title']

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meeting_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.TextField(null=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text="Choose the 'Collection' folder for the meeting's agenda, minutes and related documents")
    committee = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('meeting_datetime'),
        FieldPanel('location'),
        FieldPanel('meeting_collection'),
        FieldPanel('committee'),
    ]
```