# How to edit the default template for DateRangeField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am using `django.contrib.postgres.field.DateRangeField` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_range = DateRangeField()
```

I am rendering this in a template:

```
{% with field = form.date_range %}
{{ field.label }}
{{ field }}
{% endwith %}
```

However, this outputs 2 inputs together with no context. E.g.:

[image]

How can I edit the default template for the widget, to add "sub" labels for "start time" and "end time". E.g: [image]

There does not appear to be anything I can find in the docs.

Comment: Have you tried [custom django widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget)?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates

Comment: @JPG Yes but DateRangeField doesn't take a template input, so I don't know where to start. See here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/c2f6c05c4cc73e831b7e852eb58bd6d7a83fa46c/django/contrib/postgres/forms/ranges.py#L99

Comment: @EneP Thanks, but same problem as JPG, the ModeField doesn't take an input

Comment: model field don't take the input, but, the form field does - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878475/django-modelform-override-widget)

Comment: It takes `widget` as an argument. Then you have to create your custom widget with a custom template.

Comment: @JPG so how does one separate the two inputs in the widget template? In the django source code it just repeats the same `base_field`